# armazenar consulta SQL em Session para posterior processamento

Tags: php, session, banco-de-dados

Gostaria de armazenar uma consulta SQL em uma session, ou seja, todos os campos e seus respectivos valores.

Eu diria que são uns 12 campos, e uns 150 registros em média.

A ideia é não precisar consultar o banco de dados toda vez que precisar, e sim apenas uma vez e as outros apenas trabalhar em cima das informações que já foram registradas na session.

Isso poderia ser ruim de alguma forma, isso exigiria do servidor em qual sentido, espaço em disco? CxB vale apena?, Será que isso tornaria as respostas mais rápidas(já que não consulto mais o BD desta forma) ?

Answer (score 1):

De forma sucinta, sim. Tornaria seu aplicativo mais rápido já que não faria consultas no banco de dados, porém e importante ter em mente a confiabilidade dos  dados. Você precisa criar formas de garantir que os dados de sessão sejam os mesmo encontrados no banco de dados.

Seria interessante avaliar em seu caso sistemas de cache como o redis ou memcached. Acredito que isso já faria seu aplicativo mais rápido e mais robusto.

Comment: Session é armazenada no Disco? Então mudar de Banco de Dados para Disco não mudaria muito, memcached parece ser a solução para mim, vou ler mais sobre isso, value!